# I cannot limit Java heap size

Tags: java

I've set java heap size limit with Xmx128m in "idea64.vmoptions" file of Intellij. However, even though I'm allocating gigabytes of memory in my code, the program still works, I don't get any not enough memory error.

What is the explanation of this behaviour.

PS:Intellij reads the file "idea64.vmoptions", I checked it, that is, when I set it to Xmx16m, even the Intellij cannot start.

Thanks

Comment: In what way exactly are you allocating gigabytes of memory?

Comment: I'm simply putting objects into a hashmap in a while loop.

Comment: The amount seems very small. I wouldn't be surprised if there was some minimum setting that you realistically can't go below.

Comment: Are maybe those settings only valid for IntelliJ itself but not for processes it starts when executing your program?

Comment: You might be right @Sebi, any idea where can I limit the heap space for processes it starts.

Comment: I found it, it is under run/edit configurations "vm options". Thanks everyone.

Comment: @SanyoMn Java has no run/edit configurations. Are you talking about Eclipse maybe?

Comment: @glglgl I'm talking about Intellij editor

Answer (score 2):

I think, `idea64.vmoptions` sets the options required for running IntelliJ Idea itself. It does not control the options for running java programs inside IntelliJ.

Check the [Edit Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configurations.html) of the your respective project type. For example, in [configuration of a jar application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-jar-application.html): `VM options` box is present to set the java options required to run the jar file. Setting `-Xmx128m` in this box should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

vm options declared in idea64.vmoptions is only used for intelliJ to lauch. For project specific configurations can be done through 
Editing "Run"->"Run/Debug COnfigurations" in intelliJ idea.